# SQL case with exists not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

The idea is to check for the last time the systems were synced up by selecting the start time of the last sync. The problem is that the table that holds the sync info is new and as it moves to production the table will be empty so this query breaks the system because it does not return anything:

```
select ST_DT_TM
from SYNCJOBLOG
where SYS_ID = 'MF' and STAT_CDE = 'FN'
and SYNC_ID = (select MAX(SYNC_ID)
               from SYNCJOBLOG
               where SYS_ID = 'MF' and STAT_CDE = 'FN')
```

I've tried going the route of using a case to check if anything exists like this:

```
select case
          when exists (select ST_DT_TM
                       from SYNCJOBLOG
                       where SYS_ID = 'MF')
          then ST_DT_TM
          else ''
       end as ST_DT_TM
from SYNCJOBLOG
where SYS_ID = 'MF' and STAT_CDE = 'FN'
and SYNC_ID = (select MAX(SYNC_ID)
               from [XREFDB].[dbo].[SYNCJOBLOG]
               where SYS_ID = 'MF' and STAT_CDE = 'FN'))
```

When something does exist in the table then it works but if nothing does then it returns an empty set of rows and breaks the system. If I take out the outer where clause and nothing is in the table then it works to return the blank row but if something is in the table then it returns multiple rows and I can't have that. Is there another way to go about checking if anything exists in the table and if not then return a blank row otherwise just return the row of the max SYNC_ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your system code to check the count of records retunred and solve your issue that way.  If that isn't possible try:

```
select ST_DT_TM
from SYNCJOBLOG
where SYS_ID = 'MF' and STAT_CDE = 'FN'
and SYNC_ID = (select MAX(SYNC_ID)
               from SYNCJOBLOG
               where SYS_ID = 'MF' and STAT_CDE = 'FN')
union
select ''
where not exists(
select 1 
from SYNCJOBLOG
where SYS_ID = 'MF' and STAT_CDE = 'FN'
and SYNC_ID = (select MAX(SYNC_ID)
               from SYNCJOBLOG
               where SYS_ID = 'MF' and STAT_CDE = 'FN'))
```

Comment: Thanks! Don't know why I didn't think about this but in any case it helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select top 1 ST_DT_TM
from (
    select ST_DT_TM,
       0 as IsAlternate
    from SYNCJOBLOG
    where SYS_ID = 'MF' and STAT_CDE = 'FN'
    and SYNC_ID = (select MAX(SYNC_ID)
                   from SYNCJOBLOG
                   where SYS_ID = 'MF' and STAT_CDE = 'FN')

    union all

    select 0 as ST_DT_TM, 1 as IsAlternate
) t
order by IsAlternate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just outer join back to the same table, or a CTE?

```
with CTE as (
select MAX(SYNC_ID) as sync_id
               from SYNCJOBLOG
               where SYS_ID = 'MF' and STAT_CDE = 'FN')

select s1.ST_DT_TM
from SYNCJOBLOG s1
left outer join CTE
  on s1.sync_id = cte.sync_id
where s1.SYS_ID = 'MF' and s1.STAT_CDE = 'FN'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are sys-ids ='MF' but with st_dt_tm empty so this should fix it:

```
select case
          when exists (select ST_DT_TM
                       from SYNCJOBLOG
                       where SYS_ID = 'MF')
          then ST_DT_TM
          else ''
       end as ST_DT_TM
from SYNCJOBLOG
where SYS_ID = 'MF' and STAT_CDE = 'FN'
and isnull(st_dt_tm,'')<>''
and SYNC_ID = (select MAX(SYNC_ID)
               from [XREFDB].[dbo].[SYNCJOBLOG]
               where SYS_ID = 'MF' and STAT_CDE = 'FN'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL(ST_DT_TM,'') AS 'ST_DT_TM'
FROM SYNCJOBLOG
```

Essentially, `ISNULL` will test the first parameter, if it's null, it'll return whatever's in the second parameter (in this case, an empty string).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx